# WatchOS SwiftUI App Keeps Opening on Wrist Raise

Tags: swiftui, watchos, healthkit, ios-background-mode

We have a SwiftUI watch app that has the workout processing background mode. Every time our users raise their wrist the app opens. I understand that this is one of the abilities granted by Apple with the given background mode for active workouts. I wonder if there is a way for us to programmatically turn off this ability, given that this also drains the users battery.

Thanks

We have tried looking for a way to control the abilities of the workout session but have not been able to find the specific way to turn off the watch opening ability.